# How to update the selectedOption in the Select component from react-select?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, react-select

I am trying to create a custom dropdown component using the react-select library. I want a tick icon on the option I select in the menu list. I am facing some difficulties here:
I am trying to update the singleValue component but it is not working. Here is my code:

```
const CustomOptions = ({ children, ...props }) => {
        return (
            <components.SingleValue {...props}>
                <div className={styles.customValue}>
                    {children}
                    <i className="icon-post_reply"/>

                </div>
            </components.SingleValue>
        )
    }
    
    
    return (
        <Select
            // className={styles.select}
            onChange={handleChange}
            options={ReviewSortOptions}
            isDisabled={disable}
            defaultValue={selectedValue}
            styles={customStyles}
            isSearchable={false}
            components={{ DropdownIndicator, CustomOptions }}
            menuIsOpen
            // menuPlacement="top"
            menuPosition="fixed"
        />
    );
```

Here is the design refrence that I am trying to implement:[image: I want the icon like this beside the selected option]

Can someone please help here?